# Revert animation on exit

Tags: css

I am making a menu that should have animated "hamburger" icon inside. At first, I used `transform` and it looked nice, but I decided to add some fancier animation ;-)

They loook like this:

```
@keyframes animateFirstBar {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes animateSecoundBar {
  0%, 50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }

  51%, 100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) scaleX(.01);
  }
}

@keyframes animateThirdBar {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 200%);
  }

  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  }
}
```

And they are used like this:

```
.main-menu {
  $mainMenu: &;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: $time transform ease-in;

  &--active {
    transform: none;

    #{$mainMenu}__toggle {
      transform: none;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    #{$mainMenu}__toggle-line {
      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        animation: $time animateFirstBar forwards;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation: $time animateSecoundBar forwards;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation: $time animateThirdBar forwards;
      }
    }
  }

  &__toggle {
    width: $width;
    height: $width - 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    top: 0;
    background: yellow;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    transition: $time transform ease-in, $time background linear;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
  }

  &__toggle-line {
    width: 60%;
    height: $lineHeight;
    display: block;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transition: $time transform ease-in;
    top: (50% - ($lineHeight/2));

      &:nth-of-type(1) { 
        animation: none;
        transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
      }

      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        animation: none;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      }

      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        animation: none;
        transform: translate(-50%, 200%);
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the example here: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/jrzKKR?editors=0100

My problem is, I don't know how to revert the animation on "exit" (on removing the `--active` modificator). I don't want to write another animations or add another class that will be removed over time with JS.

Comment: You may use `backwards` animation direction, but I guess you still have to set another class

Comment: I tried using `alternate-reverse`, but with no avail. Can you post some examples?

Comment: See you fixed it, nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. I had to add another class, trigger it with JS and write another set of animations that flowed in reverse.

Animations:

```
@keyframes animateFirstBar {
  0% { transform: translate(-50%, $spacing * -100%); }
  60% { transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-#{$rotation}deg); }
}

@keyframes revertFirstBar {
  100% { transform: translate(-50%, $spacing * -100%); }
  60% { transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
  0% { transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-#{$rotation}deg); }
}

@keyframes animateSecoundBar {
  0%, 60% { transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
  61%, 100% { transform: translate(-50%, 0) scaleX(.01); }
}

@keyframes revertSecoundBar {
  0%, 60% { transform: translate(-50%, 0) scaleX(.01); }
  61%, 100% { transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
}

@keyframes animateThirdBar {
  0% { transform: translate(-50%, $spacing * 100%); }
  60% { transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(#{$rotation}deg); }
}

@keyframes revertThirdBar {
  0% { transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(#{$rotation}deg); }
  60% { transform: translate(-50%, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-50%, $spacing * 100%); } 
}
```

`revert*Bar` are going with one class, `animate*Bar` with another.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I have already implemented this hamburger button with transition and transform and I think it is satisfied what you want to archive. I haven't done it with your approach using animation. But please take a look at this snippet to see the idea.

```js
function toggleMenu(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}

/*
Orginal article - https://github.com/trungk18/Animated-Navigation-Menu-Icons-with-CSS3
*/
```

```css
/*Menu container*/

.content {
  max-width: 40em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.icon-container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5em 5em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.change {
  /*Rotate first bar*/
  /*Fade out the second bar-*/
  /*Reduce width the second bar-*/
  /*Rotate last bar*/
}
.change.icon-5 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.change .bar-10 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, -3px) scaleX(0.7);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, -3px) scaleX(0.7);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, -3px) scaleX(0.7);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, -3px) scaleX(0.7);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(8px, -3px) scaleX(0.7);
}
.change .bar-12 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 3px) scaleX(0.7);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 3px) scaleX(0.7);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 3px) scaleX(0.7);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 3px) scaleX(0.7);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, 3px) scaleX(0.7);
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <div class="icon-container icon-5" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
    <span class="bar bar-10"></span>
    <span class="bar bar-11"></span>
    <span class="bar bar-12"></span>
  </div>
</section>

<!--Full pen: http://codepen.io/trungk18/pen/jrrXjz-->
```

Comment: This (2nd example) was my initial animation, but I want it more complex. Unfortunately, it can't be done with transitions as it requires two transforms ran separately (at different frames).

Comment: Yeah, I saw it is more complicated. I guess you should write another class. Do you prefer to use JS for this animation ?

Comment: I'd rather not, but I think I will have to eventually.